# Custom auth and social auth in the same Azure Mobile App Service

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services

I need to allow authentication using my ASP.Net Identity from the MVC app (merged into the Mobile App service project) and from the mobile client (Android). Furthermore, I need to allow social authentication providers (Facebook and Google, to be exactly) to be used from the mobile client.

Adrian Hall's book says that for custom auth to work we should not configure the other authentication providers. So, how can I enable both forms of authentication?

Answer (score 1):

I don't remember saying that.  I'll have to check.  You need to be careful though.

In your MVC app, you need to decide on ASP.NET identity or App Service Identity.  If you choose ASP.NET identity, then you have to decide how your mobile application is going to authenticate - you are in completely custom area.  If you are using App Service Identity, you need to decide how your application is going to authenticate (since the redirect can only go to one place).

I'd probably do App Service Identity.  Configure Facebook and Google first.  Then create a custom mobile auth endpoint.  For your MVC side, configure a redirect page that displays the "choose your auth provider" page and then directs the user to the appropriate page - Google (/.auth/login/google) or
Facebook (/.auth/login/facebook) or custom (which you will create).

All the redirects will then point back to the callback page so the tokens get stored properly.

Comment: Hello Adrian, sorry for posting on several places. The part I mentioning is from Chapter 2 and says this: "You must turn on Authentication / Authorization in your App Service. Set the Action to take when request is not authenticated to Allow Request (no action) and do not configure any of the supported authentication providers.".

Comment: I just need to enable Facebook and Google auth for Android users. The MVC app is just the admin dashboard and won't have the option to log in using social providers. Are your suggestions based on a merged or separate MVC and mobile apps?

Comment: I'm trying to understand how can I create the controller for the custom auth endpoint and use it on my MVC app.

Comment: If it's a management interface to the database, I'd just do a straight up MVC app that happens to point to the same database.  Then keep the mobile app separate.  They can both run on the same (basic or higher) app service plan so you aren't being charged twice.  You can then use separate auth on the mobile side vs. the admin side.